# SymmetricDS Numeric Overflow

Tags: symmetricds

I've got 2 databases with the exact same design and I'm receiving an error from SymmetricDS when trying to insert specific records from the Active database to the Passive.

I'm getting the following error: 'Numeric overflow in conversion of value 211 to type Tinyint'. The data has no problem going into the Active database from our application, but the replication to the Passive is raising an error. Also, I'm able to insert the same values in the passive database manually.

Is SymmetricDS doing some type of data conversion during the insert? I'm trying to understand where and why this could be happening.

Thanks,
Kaleb

Comment: more can be deduced about the problem from symmetricds's logs on the target database. you'll see the exact insert statement and the concrete data

Comment: From what I can gather there is an issue with the default behaviour of how TINYINT is handled by SQL Server (0 to 255) and JDBC (-128 to 127). I am able to take the insert statement from the log and run it just fine in SSMS.

Comment: If nothing else you can implement your own 'DatabaseWriterFilterAdapter` and manipulate the data so it's successfully inserted by JDBC

Comment: I was also talking to support about this. Confirmed as a new bug and they already have a fix that will be built in the next point release which should be early this week. 

Thanks Boris.

Comment: This has been taken care of in version 3.7.1.